# How to install APK Expansion Files without hosting on Developer Console?

Tags: android, video, copy-protection, apk-expansion-files

I have an requirement in such a way that I have to show few video tutorials which are large in size and should be not copied by the users. The videos should be shown strictly inside the Application only. So i would go with an option of having Expansion Files and then download the videos but I shouldn't host the App on Google Play as the Application should run offline. The App will be distributed to the Students. So how can I add the Expansion Files to the Application directly without hosting them on Google Developer Console. Device will not install the app if its size more than 50 MB. Videos are static, they should be copy protected and also should run offline. Is there any other alternative to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Is there a valid answer? I want to develop an Android app with my favorites videos and songs for offline use. I think this is the accepted approach.. If you had a solution, please share it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can host the videos on your server and create a video view and stream the videos... This will make your app of less size too...

Comment: Sorry to mention the keyword offline in the question. App should run the offline that is why I went for apk expansion files which is also not the requirement for the client.

Comment: then what is the problem create a expansion file and upload it with your app and it should work fine but your apk size will increase..

Comment: have you got my question, I said you I cannot upload the expansion file on developer console.